# getRelationshipOrder() returning null

Tags: apex, describefieldresult

I'm trying this simple statement and getting `null`, shouldn't this be returning `1` since its a master-detail relationship? I've tried at API V40,41,42. Is my syntax wrong?

Here's the relevant documentation on [`DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm).

Anonymous script yielding null:

```
System.debug('relationshipOrder : ' + OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder());
```

EDIT: My previous example was an attempt to make it more generic since not everyone has Work Orders enabled, my actual issue was with WorkOrderId on WorkOrderLineItem which is a MD relationship) also returning null.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuHYF.jpg (screenshot of relationship)

```
WorkOrderLineItem.WorkOrderId.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a Lookup relationship. The expected return value is null. Some standard objects allow Rollup Summary fields despite this configuration. See, for example, this delivered Idea:

> ## [Roll-up Summary Fields for Standard Objects (Opp-Opp Line in Winter 08)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk1AAC)
>
> The recently announced Summer 07 feature for Roll-up Summary fields is a great step forward. However, it only allows roll-up summaries to be created when a custom, master-detail relationship exists. It would be tremendously useful to extend that same functionality to standard objects and the existing relationships. For example...
>
> Example 1
>   Create a Roll-up Summary field on the Account object that calculates the SUM of all related Opportunities where Stage = "Closed/Won." This is an obvious win for organizations that wish to easily identify the value of a particular customer in terms of sold business.
>
> Example 2
>   Create a Roll-up Summary field on the Account object that calculates the COUNT of all related Cases where Type or Status = X. Use your imagination but this could be an easy way for support organizations to identify how many cases a customer has submitted versus their paid support agreement.
>
> Example 3
>   Create a Roll-up Summary field on the Opportunity Product (line item) object that calculates the COUNT of all related Schedule Entries or the MIN/MAX date for related Schedule Entries. This would be an easy way to show - directly on the Opportunity related list for Products - how many monthly installments have been planned for a product or the first/last month that payment is expected.

Comment: oops well my actual issue is with: WorkOrderLineItem.WorkOrderId.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder() I was just trying to create a more generic example.

Comment: any thoughts on why it would not work for WorkOrderId? I've verified that is a MD relationship

Comment: How did you verify? I thought there weren't any detail Standard Objects.

Comment: It looks like the relationship between WorkOrder and WorkOrderLineItem is : https://imgur.com/eCTxjCV

Comment: Please edit that into your post instead. Might be that it only returns values for custom M-D, or maybe it's a bug. Hard to say.

Comment: will do, also ill submit a ticket through the partner portal